# Uncaught ReferenceError: picturePath is not defined

Tags: jquery, undefined

I'm doing a very basic puzzle moving game here to do with my uni course, I have all the code down so far however i'm missing something and i'm pulling my hair out over it without much progress so far, I get the error that the function picturePath is not defined, but I dont know where about to do that or how exactly. Anyone able to help me out. I've included the code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbZQYB

```
$('#difficult').on('click', function() {
    $('#dialog').remove();
    $('#picturePuzzle').css('background-image', 'none');
    setupPicturePuzzle(picturePath, 5);
});
```

This is where the first error occurs, lines 84-88

Comment: `picturePath` is undefined or does exist.

Comment: as I said, I understand that is the problem, I'm just unaware of the fix

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling getPicturePuzzleDifficulty() without passing picturePath as a parameter (or defining it in the function).

Comment: you could try 'getPicturePuzzleDifficulty(picturePath)' instead; picturePath is already passed into the calling function so probably should have have a value

Answer (score 0):

```
setupPicturePuzzle(picturePath, 5);
```

so:

```
setupPicturePuzzle(5);
```

```
//because this defined
.css('background-image', 'url("' + $(picture).attr('src') + '")');
```

and add css so:

```
$(elem).css({
    a: a,
    b: b
});
```